# Apache Camel - Return 200 status code and send to queue

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to set up an API method with camel that will immediately return a 200 status code and forward the request to a ActiveMQ queue to be processed asynchronously, but I don't know how to send the response, I can only route it to the queue. This is what I have so far:

```
rest("/setStatus")
            .get()
            .route().from("direct:setStatusRest")
            .to("iasJms:setStatus");
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
rest("/setStatus")
    .get()
    .route()
    .to("jms:setStatus?exchangePattern=InOnly"); // send a message to the queue
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I see that this will make the message on way, but is it going to immediately return 200 to the original request?

Comment: Yes, because `InOnly` message exchange pattern means that it is an [Event Message (fire and forget)](http://camel.apache.org/event-message.html).  As the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html#JMS-JmsProducer) says it doesn't wait for the reply.

Comment: I tested this but it's not working.  When a message is InOnly, there is no out, so response code and body are both null

Comment: Have you tried with the same what I posted? I mean you've added the `exchangePattern=InOnly` to the producer? I've just tried it and I got back 200 OK

Comment: you are right, I was getting a null response code in the junit test, but when running the app and hitting the rest api I got 200 code. thanks!